# How to convert ISO-8859-1 charset to normal string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encoding, character-encoding

I have a asp.net application and I uses ISO-8859-1 charset. But It is not OK. In the postback, I got ISO-8859-1 keycode. But the application response next time, it is display like this. How can convert to normal fonts.

```
&#4145;&#4116;&#4145;&#4096;&#4140;&#4100;&#4153;&#4152;&#4124;&#4140;&#4152;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
 var normalText= HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedText);
```

Comment: The original post is tagged vb.net, but that is C#.

Comment: not a big deal, convert using any free C# to VB.net converter.      Dim encoding__1 As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
Dim normalText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedText)